# Why isn't this working? I tried to use move in shutil in multiple ways, but none of them seem to work. What can I do?

Tags: python, operating-system, shutil

```
import os
import shutil

dir_src = (r"C:\Users\Razer Blade\Desktop\src")
dir_dst = (r"C:\Users\Razer Blade\Desktop\destination")

for file in dir_src:
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(file, dir_src), os.path.join(file, dir_dst))
```

Comment: How, exactly, is it not working?  Do you get an error?  Do you get unwanted results?  Do you get no results at all?

Comment: For one thing, I think you have the arguments in the wrong order `os.path.join(file, dir_src)`.  The file should be last.

Answer (score 1):

You are not iterating over the files. Try something like this:

```py
import glob
import os

dir_src = (r"C:\Users\Razer Blade\Desktop\src")
dir_dst = (r"C:\Users\Razer Blade\Desktop\destination")

path = os.path.join(dir_src, "*.txt")
files = glob.glob(path)

for file in files:
    #do something with the file
    pass
```